# Sliding band-like UI control element for iOS and how do I mimic it?

Tags: iphone, uicontrol

The mobile edition of AP News has a sliding band type UI control that allows you to switch between "Headlines", "Most Recent" any number of other sections. It's akin to a sliding segment bar.

Does anyone know how one would go about mimicking this?

And is there a name for this type of control?

[image: sliding segment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a very similar control named `TTTabStrip` in [three20 Library](https://github.com/facebook/three20) :

[image: TTTabStrip]

By tweaking / styling it you should achieve what you're looking for...

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a UIScrollView with `pagingEnabled` turned on. Your controller class would implement the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol, and in `scrollViewDidScroll:`, check the scroll view’s `contentOffset` to determine which item is currently selected.